# Organizing Project Libraries

Tags: java, git, gradle, intellij-idea

I know this is a problem solved a long time ago, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about this.

I have a multipart project as follows:

Native-Module(C based) --> Core(business logic, Java) --> UI/API module/layer

The native module and core module will remain the same in all variations. However, the UI/API layer will be different depending on the use. When used as a desktop application it will just be a JavaFX or ReactNative layer. When used on a server the UI/API layer will be a layer that will communicate with a control server via REST.

To be clear, all of this is already built and working just fine. But I've been importing/copying the library of each module to the next module manually. My issue is how do I manage all of the individual modules in git or gradle in a more automated way? I should also be clear that while I use git and gradle and have basic understanding of both, my knowledge is lacking to tackle this on my own. I have separate repositories setup for each module. I am familiar with git's submodule, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs. I'm trying to set everything up so that new guys starting to work on the project will have a straight-forward setup process.

I've searched around but haven't been able to find and resources that seem to fit my scenario, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad, so perhaps I shouldn't answer until it gets a bit more targeted, but I'll give it a go anyway.

In general, the build output of each module will be deployed as versioned artifacts (e.g. jar files) to a repository (e.g. https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) and your projects will define dependencies on those versioned artifacts that are stored in the repository.  Then the build system (e.g. gradle) will pull the defined artifacts into your build automatically.  You setup this local repository, such as artifactory, yourself and configure your gradle build to look at this local repository for artifacts, in addition to looking at the central repositories where common open source artifacts are stored.

That's the overall high-level approach.  The detail of how you manage this in your environment, I can't provide here (for one, I am not familiar enough with gradle to provide a meaningful concrete answer using it).

In terms of an example which uses some of the technology you mention in your question (multi-module project with native libs, java code and gradle build), the JavaFX system has all of that and source code can be found here https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx.  However, JavaFX is a large, sophisticated project which has native portions targeting different native systems (OS X, Windows, Linux) and your particular application may not need as much customization as JavaFX.  Still, perhaps you might get something out of reviewing how the JavaFX developers tackled this problem.

Another consideration is the separation of concerns between the build system and generated artifacts and the deployment system and deployed services.  For some of your components, you may not need to have runtime or compile dependencies via libraries imported in a gradle type dependency management system.  Instead, as you describe in your question, you have a loose coupling via a REST API, so the UI layer doesn't actually have a compile time dependency on the server.  So the REST based portion might be deployed to a local server, or an Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud or Microsoft Azure server.  If AWS, a cloud formation template might be used to push the service out to an EC2 box via an Ansible script.  Automating that kind of stuff is outside the scope of artifactory, git, gradle, etc. and can get kind of complicated pretty fast and is beyond what I would be prepared to talk about in detail here.